# Mongodb command for generate a new ObjectId using Extended JSON

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a collection like the one below

[image]

I need to push a new object into the "stores" array using extended json.

How can I instruct the Mongodb to create a new ObjectId for the attribute _id ?

I'm wondering something like this:

```
{
  '_id' : { '$oid' : '$<here_some_command_to_generate_new_oid_automatically>' },
  'address' : 'my store address',
  'contact' : 'John Doe'
}
```

Comment: If a document is inserted into MongoDB without any `_id`, the server will automatically assign an ObjectId as the `_id` of that document. Maybe clarify why you want the ObjectId as `$oid` and how you are inserting documents.

Comment: MongoDB uses BSON Types to store documents. JSON represents a subset of the types supported by BSON. When collection data is exported to a JSON file, for example, the `ObjectId` field is exported as `OID` (the MongoDB Extended JSON); its representation in JSON is `{"$oid": "<id>"}`, where the `<id>` is a 24-character hexadecimal string of the `ObjectId`. The `{"$oid": "<id>"}` represents the value for the `_id` key in the document (and it is represented as a JSON object).

Comment: _continued..._ The exported JSON file can be used to import into a MongoDB collection, using mongoimport (and the `"$oid"` will be transformed to `ObjectId`). As such you cannot use `$` prefixed field names for documents (it will generate an error). So the question: _why do you want to use the Extended JSON version of `ObjectId` for a field/value?_

Comment: @kevinadi Yes, I know that for a new document the _id will be created automatically. But, as shown in my example I have an array of objects and I need that each object has an unique (global) id. I would'nt like to create this id in my external application, but instead I would like to leverage Mongodb to create it.

Comment: @kevinadi This model maps a business process. I have an mobile application where based on a document _id I get a set of objects (in the example the stores[]). And one id for each object of stores is need to identify where some process occured.

Comment: @prasad_ I'm using Pentaho Data Intragation (PDI) to insert and update documents in the Mongodb. To use PDI I need to prepare the data in JSON. That's the reason why I need to use Extended JSON. All my process works fine, except the new one that I need to finish. As I said in a previous comment I could generate this id outside of mongo, but I would like to have it being generated by the mongodb itself.

Comment: @KleysonRios as i understand, the documents that are coming inside an array, you want `_id` to be present for those.
so, in this type of case what i do is, i create another schema and reference it in parent schema.
in this way it creates `_id` , for the child one. although i'm not sure, in your case it would be possible or not.

Comment: I don't believe this is possible.  The MongoDB database only generates ids for top-level documents.  If you must have unique ids for the embedded document, you can generate them programmatically with all of the MongoDB drivers.  However, you would be much better off overall to modify your database such that you have a Cities collection whose documents have an `ObjectId` _id field and a `city_name` field, and a Stores collection whose documents have an `ObjectId` _id field and an `ObjectId` CityId field in addition to your address and contacts field.

Comment: @SaikatChakrabortty yes, it would be possible but is not the best option. So, looks like that the Mongodb has no command to generate a new _id under extended json.

Comment: @VictorWilson yes. That would be an option but not so good for my needs. Thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless I misunderstood you ,if you just need to generate using client side you can do it the same way any driver would do for top level documents.

In java to generate extended json version you could use `JsonWriterSettings` with output mode as `JsonMode.Extended`. Something like

```
JsonWriterSettings setting = JsonWriterSettings.builder().outputMode(JsonMode.EXTENDED).build();
Document id = new Document("_id", new ObjectId());
String extendedIdJson = id.toJson(setting);// {'_id' : { '$oid' : '507f191e810c19729de860ea' }}
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution is specify like this in the json "*id*":{"$oid": "<ObjectId()>"},

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This will not generate a unique id. All the ids I'm getting are `3c4f626a656374496428293e`